# Filemaker Pro Advanced - Scripting import from ODBC with variable target table

Tags: import, odbc, filemaker

I have several tables I'm importing from ODBC using the import script step.  Currently, I have an import script for each and every table.  This is becoming unwieldy as I now have nearly 200 different tables.

I know I can calculate the SQL statement to say something like "Select * from " & $TableName.  However, I can't figure out how to set the target table without specifying it in the script.  Please, tell me I'm being dense and there is a good way to do this!

Thanks in advance for your assistance,
Nicole Willson
Integrated Research

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the target table of an import has to be hard coded in FileMaker up through version 12 if you're using the `Import Records` script step. I can think of a workaround to this, but it's rather convoluted and if you're importing a large number of records, would probably significantly increase the time to import them.

The workaround would be to not use the `Import Records` script step, but to script the creation of records and the population of data into fields yourself.

First of all, the success of this would depend on how you're using ODBC. As far as I can think, it would only work if you're using ODBC to create shadow tables within FileMaker so that FileMaker can access the ODBC database via other script steps. I'm not an expert with the other ODBC facilities of FileMaker, so I don't know if this workaround would be helpful in other cases.

So, if you have a shadow table into the remote ODBC database, then you can use a script something like the following. The basic idea is to have two sets of layouts, one for the shadow tables that information is coming from and another for the FileMaker tables that the information needs to go to. Loop through this list, pulling information from the shadow table into variables (or something like the dictionary library I wrote which you can find at https://github.com/chivalry/filemaker-dictionary). Then go to the layout linked to the target table, create a record and populate the fields.

This isn't a novice technique, however. In addition to using variables and loops, you're also going to have to use FileMaker's design functions to determine the source and destination of each field and `Set Field By Name` to put the data in the right place. But as far as I can tell, it's the only way to dynamically target tables for importing data.

Comment: This sounds like it would have a ton of overhead.  Some of my tables have over 100,000 rows every couple hours to pull in.  As it is, the import takes several minutes to complete each of these tables.

Comment: I thought of another solution, a SQL plugin. Check out http://www.mbsplugins.eu/FMExecuteSQL.shtml. It supports using the `INSERT` command in SQL. I googled "FileMaker SQL plugin" to find it. Performing the same search will bring up a few others, but this one specifically says it supports the `INSERT` command.